# If the .Net Framework based created dll is supported in the .Net Core Version

Tags: .net-core

I will developed a project in the .Net Framework based 4.5.2 Version using some data base function also.
Oledb Connection

And I will Adding the Class Library in the .Net Core Application Project. The Dll get and accept and build properly in the Application.

But , The Error got the System.Data.Oledb dll is unsupported in runtime .Why ?

Comment: OleDb is an ancient COM-based data provider framework.  Beyond it being impossible to port to the unixes, always a factor in .NETCore, Microsoft has few compelling reasons to keep supporting it.  You didn't to ask for the help you actually need.

Comment: Ok Fine...I will try to any alternative way to get Solution..Thanks for reply